# combine Date and Time into a DateTime from api response

Tags: ruby, api, datetime

What is the efficient way to combine Date and Time (strings) into a single DateTime? i am using football-api in response i am getting  time attribute in `"08:50"` these format and date attribute `"01.01.2018"` these format. I want to save in database `2018-01-01 08:50:00` format in date field.

```
a = match["formatted_date"].to_date.strftime("%Y, %m, %d")
y = a[0..3].to_i 
m = a[6..7].to_i 
d = a[10..11].to_i 
date = Date.new(y, m, d).to_datetime + Time.parse(match["time"]).seconds_since_midnight.seconds
```

Comment: Have you tried something? There is a lot of tutorials and examples in the web.

Comment: i tried with these way

a = match["formatted_date"].to_date.strftime("%Y, %m, %d")y =  a[0..3].to_i
     m = a[6..7].to_i
     d = a[10..11].to_i
     date = Date.new(y, m, d).to_datetime + Time.parse(match["time"]).seconds_since_midnight.seconds
i am getting result that i want 2018-01-01 08:50:002018-01-01 08:50:00, but is it efficient way?

Comment: Why not just `"01.01.2018 08:50".to_time` and in your case `"#{match["formatted_date"]} #{match["time"]}".to_time`?

Comment: Thank you Зелёный, your answer is efficient and simple works for me.